# Make text wrap in Row's available space

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a variable length text. I am not being able to make the text wrap inside a Row

My code is as follows

```
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,           
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      $variableLengthText,
      softWrap: true,
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I need to have two red bars of flexible width, and the text in the center. When the text is wider than the available space, the bars should not show as the text takes the whole space. This works. When the text is longer than the available space it does not wrap, I need it to wrap.

Thank you.

Comment: Try adding Expanded to the text and remove from both the Containers

Comment: @Pythony that doesn't work. If I wrap the text in expanded and remove it from the containers, the text's container (the expanded widget) will take up the whole width and the width of both containers will be 0. you can try it in dartpad. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative solution: Here we should wrap Text with ContrainedBox but we do not know the max width of Row. So maybe we can wrap Row with a LayoutBuilder, so every time before rendering the Row, we can get its max width imposed by parents. Then we can assign this as a state variable.
Later on, you can use this as maxWidth of BoxConstraint.
Following code works on dartpad, just copy & paste and run, hope it will help you.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  double maxWidthOfRow = 0;
  //String variableLengthText = 'AAAA';
  String variableLengthText = 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
          child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 200),
        child: LayoutBuilder(
          builder: (context, constraints) {
            maxWidthOfRow = constraints.maxWidth;
            print(constraints.maxWidth);
            return Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  //flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    //width:0,
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                ),
                ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: maxWidthOfRow),
                    child: Text(variableLengthText)),
                Flexible(
                  //flex: 1,
                  child: Container(
                    //width:0,
                    height: 20,
                    color: Colors.red,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          },
        ),
      )),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is new to me.

Answer (score 0):

What happens in your case is that the text does not have any particular constraint as it is in a row, so it overflows. What needs to be done is simple, determine the constraint for the text. Like this:

```dart
 Row(
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: constrainedWidth), // <---- This here controls text and makes it wrap to fit into the constrained space
          child: Text(
            strings.simCardPageGuide,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(
            height: 20,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Comment: This does not work, as I don't know the width of constrainedWidth. If I knew the max width of the text then it would work, the row itself is inside a flexible

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best approach, but please try:

```
  Size _textSize(String text, TextStyle style) {
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
        text: TextSpan(text: text, style: style), maxLines: 1, textDirection: TextDirection.ltr)
      ..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);
    return textPainter.size;
  }
  
  String variableLengthText = 'blablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablabblablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablablab';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    _textSize(variableLengthText, TextStyle(
      fontSize: 12,
      color: Colors.white,
    ),).width > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width ? Expanded(flex: 1000, child:
    Text(
      '$variableLengthText',
      softWrap: true,
    ),) : Text(
      '$variableLengthText',
      softWrap: true,
    ),
    Expanded(
      flex: 1,
      child: Container(
        height: 20,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: the width of the container where the text is is not the full width of the screen, I don't think > MediaQuery.of(context).size.width will do the trick

Comment: so, you won't know the length of Row?

Comment: I don't know it